# overcoming audio playback problems with JPlayer?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mobile, jplayer

Here's the problem:

We are using a streaming audio server called Icecast to serve not only our live audio stream, but regular MP3s as well. It works fine for all desktop browsers, but on mobile it does not work well. The audio will suddenly stop and begin again from the beginning. It does this both when the audio is played through my JPlayer installation, and when the mp3 url is opened directly in the browser and played it's not any different - it keeps stopping and starting again from the beginning. Therefor I believe it is not my jPlayer code, it is not the MP3 itself, **it is a problem between the phone and the server.**

However, if we CAN play the audio through jPlayer on mobile that somehow corrects the problem, then that would be ideal. We do not want to have to change the server setup if possible, it's easier to come up with a client-side solution than a server-side one.

Any ideas?

Here's my jPlayer code (mixed with some PHP)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#$prefix-$rstring").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "$mp3",
      });
    },
    swfPath: "$swflocation",
    supplied: "mp3",
    play: function() { 
        // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
        $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    },
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_$i",
    wmode: "window",
    globalVolume: true,
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
  });
});
```

Are there any options I can use to fix them problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: just tried the `preload: "auto"` option and that didn't work

Comment: Try looking at Icecast server access/error logs. Also you can add `error:function( event )` handler to your jPlayer code to catch jPlayer errors, `event.jPlayer.error.type` will have error code.

Comment: @DanMantyla Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the exact same problem

Comment: @HiteshBhutani no not really, I kinda forgot about this, we haven't experienced this problem recently

Comment: @DanMantyla I am having this problem only with chrome but not with Opera or FireFox. Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the best way for iphones and icecast streaming media servers to play nicely together when serving static mp3s is to put the mp3 in a .m3u file. My iphone plays a 2hr long mp3 right away when it is wrapped in an m3u, but it takes 50 seconds for it to play if I put the mp3 url directly into the browser or through a 3rd party app.

However, Android doesn't want to play the m3u, it wants to treat it like a file! So, not perfect...

Of course JPlayer can play M3Us so yay :)